# Refresh time stamp on product view (Magento)

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

I need to reload the data within a DIV, I am using a time stamp for testing purposes.

The code I have appears to work outside of Magento So I cannot see why it is not working on my Magento Site.

I am trying to achieve this using jQuery using the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('#bopa').load();
  },3000);
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="bopa">
<?php $datee = new DateTime(); echo $datee->format('H:i:s') . "\n";?>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: are you getting any js errors in console? use F12 to check

Comment: No errors in console

Answer (score 0):

your snippet will not working with native php.
according to [jQuery official Document](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you need to put first argument as same page as Object type(string url).

Comment: I have changed the code as I believe that $ conflicts with Magento Prototype.

Comment: did your console show you a ajax request ?

Comment: nothing is in console.